# Branching logic quiz -- where am I going wrong? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I am trying to develop logic for a "simple" jQuery quiz [[Fiddle here]](https://jsfiddle.net/nbcg9vq0/). The problem is, the question path is somewhat dynamic, and produces a tree structure.

For example, the first question is about pets: dog, cat, or bird? If you choose dog, it asks what breed dog. If you choose cats, it asks what breed cat. Etc. Then it delves deeper ("What color dog of this particular breed?")

The problem I am having is getting to that third set of questions. I can't get the color question to work for any of the dogs. In fact, the click handler doesn't even fire. Can anyone tell me where I've fouled this up?

Thank you in advance.

```
var questions = [{
    "text": "What's your favorite pet?",
    "choices": [
        {
            "label": "Dog",
            "path": 1
        },
        {
            "label": "Cat",
            "path": 2
        },
        {
            "label": "Bird",
            "path": 3
        },
    ]
}, {
    "text": "What breed of dog?", //1 a
    "choices": [
        {
            "label": "Golden Retriever",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Labrador",
            "path": 5
        },
        {
            "label": "Poodle",
            "path": 6
        },
    ]
}, {
    "text": "What breed of cat?", //1 b
    "choices": [
        {
            "label": "Siamese",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Persian",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Tortie",
            "path": 4
        },
    ]
}, {
    "text": "What breed of bird?", //1 c
    "choices": [
        {
            "label": "Bluebird",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Robin",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Parrot",
            "path": 4
        },
    ]
}, {
    "text": "What color Golden Retriever?", //1 a i
    "choices": [
        {
            "label": "Golden",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Sandy",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Blonde",
            "path": 4
        },
    ]
}, {
    "text": "What color Labrador?", //1 b i
    "choices": [
        {
            "label": "Black",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Chocolate",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Tan",
            "path": 4
        },
    ]
}, {
    "text": "What color Poodle?", //1 c i
    "choices": [
        {
            "label": "Ugly",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Uglier",
            "path": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "Ugliest",
            "path": 4
        },
    ]
}];

var currentQuestion = 0,
    quizComplete = false;

$(document).ready(function() {

    updateQuestion();

    if (!quizComplete) {

        $('.choice').on('click', function() {

        value = $(this).attr('value');
            currentQuestion = value;

            if (currentQuestion < questions.length) {
                updateQuestion();
            } else {
                quizComplete = true;
            }

        });

    }

});

function updateQuestion() {

    var question = questions[currentQuestion].text;
    var questionText = $(document).find(".container > .question");
    var choiceList = $(document).find(".container > .choices");
    var numChoices = questions[currentQuestion].choices.length;

    // Set question text
    $(questionText).text(question);

    // Clear current choices and update with new ones
    $(".choice").remove();

    var choice, path;
    for (i = 0; i < numChoices; i++) {
        choice = questions[currentQuestion].choices[i].label;
        path = questions[currentQuestion].choices[i].path;
        $('<div class="choice" value=' + path + '>' + choice + '</div>').appendTo(choiceList);
    }
}
```

Comment: when the list is re-created, the on click listener is removed (it's a side-affect of building a new list). Try wrapping your  $('.choice').on('click', function() {...});' in a function, and then calling that function where-ever you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(document).on('click', '.choice', function() {});` which will work even when you remove and re-add the `.choice` element. And change the `currentQuestion` to get incremented each time he/she answers so that we can track the number of questions answered.

**Update:-**

Your logic doesn't seem to be working perfect. So change the object structure slightly like the following demo

```js
var questions = {
  "text": "What's your favorite pet?",
  "choices": [{
      "label": "Dog",
      "path": 1,
      "question": {
        "text": "What breed of dog?", //1 a
        "choices": [{
            "label": "Golden Retriever",
            "path": 11,
            "question": {
              "text": "What color Golden Retriever?", //1 a
              "choices": [{
                  "label": "Golden",
                  "path": 111
                },
                {
                  "label": "Sandy",
                  "path": 112
                },
                {
                  "label": "Blonde",
                  "path": 113
                },
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "Labrador",
            "path": 12,
            "question": {
              "text": "What color Labrador?", //1 a
              "choices": [{
                  "label": "Black",
                  "path": 121
                },
                {
                  "label": "Chocolate",
                  "path": 122
                },
                {
                  "label": "Tan",
                  "path": 123
                },
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "Poodle",
            "path": 13,
            "question": {
              "text": "What color Poodle?", //1 a
              "choices": [{
                  "label": "Ugly",
                  "path": 131
                },
                {
                  "label": "Uglier",
                  "path": 132
                },
                {
                  "label": "Ugliest",
                  "path": 133
                },
              ]
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "Cat",
      "path": 2,
      "question": {
        "text": "What breed of cat?", //1 b
        "choices": [{
            "label": "Siamese",
            "path": 21,
            "question": {
              "text": "What color Siamese?", //1 a
              "choices": [{
                  "label": "white",
                  "path": 211
                },
                {
                  "label": "orange",
                  "path": 212
                },
                {
                  "label": "red",
                  "path": 213
                },
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "Persian",
            "path": 22,
            "question": {
              "text": "What color Persian?", //1 a
              "choices": [{
                  "label": "lavendar",
                  "path": 221
                },
                {
                  "label": "green",
                  "path": 222
                },
                {
                  "label": "black",
                  "path": 223
                },
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "Tortie",
            "path": 23,
            "question": {
              "text": "What color Tortie?", //1 c
              "choices": [{
                  "label": "violet",
                  "path": 231
                },
                {
                  "label": "orange",
                  "path": 232
                },
                {
                  "label": "Pink",
                  "path": 233
                },
              ]
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "Bird",
      "path": 3,
      "question": {
        "text": "What breed of bird?", //1 a
        "choices": [{
            "label": "Bluebird",
            "path": 31,
            "question": {
              "text": "What breed of Bluebird?", //1 a
              "choices": [{
                  "label": "Blue",
                  "path": 311
                },
                {
                  "label": "grey",
                  "path": 312
                },
                {
                  "label": "yellow",
                  "path": 313
                },
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "Robin",
            "path": 32,
            "question": {
              "text": "What breed of Robin?", //1 a
              "choices": [{
                  "label": "Black",
                  "path": 321
                },
                {
                  "label": "White",
                  "path": 322
                },
                {
                  "label": "Red",
                  "path": 323
                },
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "Parrot",
            "path": 33,
            "question": {
              "text": "What breed of Parrot?", //1 a
              "choices": [{
                  "label": "Multi Color",
                  "path": 331
                },
                {
                  "label": "Red",
                  "path": 332
                },
                {
                  "label": "Green",
                  "path": 333
                },
              ]
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    },
  ]
};

var quizComplete = false,
  answers = [],
  currentObj = questions;

$(document).ready(function() {

  updateQuestion();

  if (!quizComplete) {

    $('.choices').on('click', '.choice', function() {

      value = $(this).attr('value');
      answers.push($(this).html());
      //currentQuestion++;

      if (currentObj.choices[value].question) {
        currentObj = currentObj.choices[value].question;
      } else {
        quizComplete = true;
        alert("quizComplete answers : " + answers);
        answers = [];
        currentObj = questions;
      }
      updateQuestion();

    });

  }
});

function updateQuestion() {

  var question = currentObj.text;
  var questionText = $(document).find(".container > .question");
  var choiceList = $(document).find(".container > .choices");
  var numChoices = currentObj.choices.length;

  // Set question text
  $(questionText).text(question);

  // Clear current choices and update with new ones
  $(".choice").remove();

  var choice, path;
  for (i = 0; i < numChoices; i++) {
    choice = currentObj.choices[i].label;
    path = currentObj.choices[i].path;
    $('<div class="choice" value=' + i + '>' + choice + '</div>').appendTo(choiceList);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: peachpuff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
  position: relative;
}

.question {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  text-align: center;
}

.choices {
  font-family: Courier, serif;
  color: indianred;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.choice {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="question"></div>
    <div class="choices"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

click Event has to be added everytime updating a Questions. Here updated code

```js
var questions = [{
 "text": "What's your favorite pet?",
 "choices": [
  {
   "label": "Dog",
   "path": 1
  },
  {
   "label": "Cat",
   "path": 2
  },
  {
   "label": "Bird",
   "path": 3
  },
 ]
}, {
 "text": "What breed of dog?", //1 a
 "choices": [
  {
   "label": "Golden Retriever",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Labrador",
   "path": 5
  },
  {
   "label": "Poodle",
   "path": 6
  },
 ]
}, {
 "text": "What breed of cat?", //1 b
 "choices": [
  {
   "label": "Siamese",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Persian",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Tortie",
   "path": 4
  },
 ]
}, {
 "text": "What breed of bird?", //1 c
 "choices": [
  {
   "label": "Bluebird",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Robin",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Parrot",
   "path": 4
  },
 ]
}, {
 "text": "What color Golden Retriever?", //1 a i
 "choices": [
  {
   "label": "Golden",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Sandy",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Blonde",
   "path": 4
  },
 ]
}, {
 "text": "What color Labrador?", //1 b i
 "choices": [
  {
   "label": "Black",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Chocolate",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Tan",
   "path": 4
  },
 ]
}, {
 "text": "What color Poodle?", //1 c i
 "choices": [
  {
   "label": "Ugly",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Uglier",
   "path": 4
  },
  {
   "label": "Ugliest",
   "path": 4
  },
 ]
}];

var currentQuestion = 0,
    quizComplete = false;

$(document).ready(function () {

 updateQuestion();

});
//separating next Question
function nextQuestion() {
if (!quizComplete) {

  $('.choice').on('click', function() {

    value = $(this).attr('value');
   currentQuestion = value;
  
   if (currentQuestion < questions.length) {
    updateQuestion();
   } else {
        quizComplete = true;
      }

  });
    
 }
}

function updateQuestion() {

 var question = questions[currentQuestion].text;
 var questionText = $(document).find(".container > .question");
 var choiceList = $(document).find(".container > .choices");
 var numChoices = questions[currentQuestion].choices.length;

 // Set question text
 $(questionText).text(question);

 // Clear current choices and update with new ones
 $(".choice").remove();

 var choice, path;
 for (i = 0; i < numChoices; i++) {
  choice = questions[currentQuestion].choices[i].label;
  path = questions[currentQuestion].choices[i].path;
  $('<div class="choice" value=' + path + '>' + choice + '</div>').appendTo(choiceList);
 }
  //It needs to be called every update
  nextQuestion();
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: serif;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    background-color: peachpuff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    position: relative;
}
.question {
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    text-align: center;
}
.choices {
    font-family: Courier, serif;
    color: indianred;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
.choice {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <body>

     <div class="container">
         <div class="question"></div>
         <div class="choices"></div>
     </div>

 </body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```