# How to show my path in my branching QUIZ on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701628/branching-logic-quiz-where-am-i-going-wrong-javascript) and made my QUIZ based on it. Could you please tell me how to print the path the user has followed? I want to write further conditions, for example, if a user walked on path 23, then show him such a picture.

[My QUIZ](https://codepen.io/alexey-chudenkov/pen/KKpzoWj)

```js
var questions = {
  "text": "Why, besides the obvious are you buying wine today?",
  "choices": [{
      "label": "For a party",
      "path": 1,
      "question": {
        "text": "For party...", //1 a
        "choices": [{
            "label": "It's a game day baby!",
            "path": 11
          },
          {
            "label": "It's Kelly's Bach party!",
            "path": 12
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "As a gift",
      "path": 2,
      "question": {
        "text": "How much do you wanna spend?", //1 b
        "choices": [{
            "label": "$",
            "path": 21,
          },
          {
            "label": "$$",
            "path": 22,
            "question": {
              "text": "You sure? It this for...", //1 a
              "choices": [{
                  "label": "Your yoga instructor Namaste",
                  "path": 221
                },
                {
                  "label": "A spouse/significant other",
                  "path": 222
                },
                {
                  "label": "Your boss / a client",
                  "path": 223
                },
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "$$$",
            "path": 23
          },
        ]
      }
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a path value for each answers, you can just refer to the the last selected answer. so after the quiz complete:

```
alert("you have chosen the path:" + currentObj.choices[value].path );
```